# Unable to import WebService/Schema

Tags: c#, web-services

I've created a web service (.Net 3.5), but when I try and add a web reference to it from another application I get the following error:

> Custom tool error: Unable to import WebService/Schema. The parameter 'sectionGroupName' is invalid.

When I double-click it it takes me to the settings file.

> How do I get around this?

Comment: Post your service-Config-file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the sectionGroupName parameter.

**[Customizing SectionGroups and Sections in Web.config in C#](http://itneeds4u.blogspot.com/2011/02/customizing-sectiongroups-and-sections.html)**

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, thanks. My app.config file wasn't up to date and had an empty <configSections> section. I commented it all out, then refreshed my current webservices and the correct entries appeared in the file